# Google Maps marker not appearing when map is initialized

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm newbie to Google Map API.  I know this is probably a simple one.  Code works as needed except I cannot get marker to initially display on map.  Marker is waiting for a click event to display marker.  Need initial marker to display on map when map first loads so it can be dragged.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="libs/jq.ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places,visualization&sensor=false"></script>


 <script>
var initialLocation;
var map;
var marker;
var latlon;
var lat;
var lon;


     //---------------------------------------------------
      getLocation();
      //--------------------------------------------------- 
      function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
  var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize,showError,
    {enableHighAccuracy:true,timeout:timeoutVal,maximumAge:0}

  );
        lat = position.coords.latitude; 
        lon = position.coords.longitude;

    }

  }

 //---------------------------------------------------

function initialize() {             
    var myOptions={
    center:latlon,
    zoom:15,
    zoomControl:true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
    style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };          


       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

              myListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                    placeMarker(event.latLng);
                    google.maps.event.removeListener(myListener);
                    });

              google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function(event) {
                    placeMarker(event.latLng);
                    google.maps.event.removeListener(myListener);
                    });




        // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
             if(navigator.geolocation) {
               // browserSupportFlag = true;
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
               }, function() {
                showError;
                });
                }

                function placeMarker(location) {

                  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
            icon:'map_icon3.png',
            animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        map: map,
                        draggable: true
                    });
        marker.setMap(map);
                    map.setCenter(location);
                    var markerPosition = marker.getPosition();
                    populateInputs(markerPosition);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "drag", function (mEvent) {
                    populateInputs(mEvent.latLng);
                    });
                }

                function populateInputs(pos) {
                    document.getElementById("t1").value=pos.lat()
                    document.getElementById("t2").value=pos.lng();
                }
            }


//-------------------------------------------------------------------
function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code) 
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML="User Denied Geolocation"
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML="Location Data Unavailable"
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML="Request Timed Out"
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML="Unknown Error Occurred"
      break;
    }
  }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
        <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" />
        <input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where in your code are you attempting to display the marker on page load?

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that the image file that you have mentioned under icon while creating the marker is accessible i.e. the path to it is correct.

I changed the icon image to the following and the marker was visible:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    icon:'http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png',
                    animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true
                });
```

I was unable to get the position through the browser. 
It kept giving me an error saying :

```
position is not defined
lat = position.coords.latitude;
```

To avoid this I changed the latlon variable in myOptions in initialize function to center on a fixed point.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(19.16981,72.85434);        
var myOptions={
center:latlng,
zoom:15,
zoomControl:true,
zoomControlOptions: {
style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

The listener that you have added for the map drag event gives an error as it does not return a MouseEvent and hence no position is obtained. Even if this listener is omitted the code will still work.

As per the v3 documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

drag       None     This event is repeatedly fired while the user drags the map.

Hope this helps you out. Do let me know if it works.